# Add code only for blog posts

Tags: php, conditional-tags

I am trying to run a code only in blog posts, and another code only in single pages.
But I can't even make a single working php if statement, that contains a wordpress conditional tag.

In footer.php, I tried to make some simple functions

```
if( is_singular() ) {
    // should show work in singular pages, bot is not working
}
```

In the below code, the code4 get's executed, on the front page

```
if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
  code1;
} elseif ( is_front_page() ) {
  code2;
} elseif ( is_home() ) {
  code3;
} else {
  code4; 
}
```

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?
And how can I make some codes only for blog posts, and some only for single pages?

Answer (score 0):

It’s just that you got it a bit wrong - it’s actually

```
if(is_single())
```

(not singular). If you want to address pages in general (not posts I assume), you would use

```
if(is_page())
```

. If you need to address a specific page you could use its ID like so

```
if(is_page(13))
```

where 13 would be the ID of the page. But you have a lot of options - see http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags .

However, of course you can use conditional tags in both header and footer (i.e. outside the loop) to tailor your template better ;).

Comment: If you are unsure of how to correctly form PHP just take a look at the examples, it is a bit tricky at first, but you’re getting used to it.

Comment: It's not that, I tried other conditionals, but they all return negative.

Comment: So, none is actually working? Can you try putting up `<?php if(is_single()) { echo 'This is working!'; } ?>` into your footer.php and see whether it is being shown on the website/in the source code?